# How to show first two rows of a hidden table in another table

Tags: javascript

I have a table in a hidden modal that populates dynamically anywhere from 0 to 10 rows. I need to get the data from the first two rows of this table to show in another table on my page. Also, if the hidden table has more than 2 rows, it displays a button to show the hidden table. My issue is, my code only works if the hidden table has 2 or more rows. I'm new to javascript and unsure how to correct this...

```
function populatetable {
  // checks for table cell id in the hidden table
  var rowcheck = document.getElementById('cell1')
  var rowyes = document.getElementById('thetable').contains(rowcheck);
  var showbutton = document.getElementById('thebutton');
  // when button is still hidden
  if (document.getElementById('thetable').getElementsByTagName('tr').length <=2 && rowyes == true) {
  // variables for table data in hidden table's first row
  var data1 = document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML;
  var data2 = document.getElementById('td2').innerHTML;
  // variable for table data in hiddent table's second row
  var data3 = document.getElementById('td3').innerHTML;
  var data4 = document.getElementById('td4').innerHTML;
  // populates visible table from rows in hidden table
  document.getElementById('vtd1').innerHTML = data1;
  document.getElementById('vtd2').innerHTML = data2;
  document.getElementById('vtd3').innerHTML = data3;
  document.getElementById('vtd4').innerHTML = data4;
  }

  if else (document.getElementById('thetable').getElementsByTagName('tr').length > 2 && rowyes == true) {
  showbutton.style.display = 'block';
  var data1 = document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML;
  var data2 = document.getElementById('td2').innerHTML;
  var data3 = document.getElementById('td3').innerHTML;
  var data4 = document.getElementById('td4').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('vtd1').innerHTML = data1;
  document.getElementById('vtd2').innerHTML = data2;
  document.getElementById('vtd3').innerHTML = data3;
  document.getElementById('vtd4').innerHTML = data4;
  }
}
```

This all however, only works if the hidden table only has at least 2 rows. Any ideas?

Comment: The "D" in `document.getElementById()` should not be capital, FYI.

Comment: `'vtd4;` should be `'vtd4'`

Comment: fix  all the syntax errors in your code and then we can have a look.

Comment: Tables have a *rows* property, consider: `document.getElementByID('thetable').rows.length > 2`.

Comment: apologies, first time posting, made some typos. They have been corrected.

Comment: `if else` doesn't make much sense. Where is your `if`-condition?

Comment: Please add your html markup for both tables

Answer (score 0):

Consider this school case = we access the elements of an html table by their reference in rows / cells:
(it is also better to use `textContent` to read their content, if it is only textual)

if you want a identical copy of rows, it should be better to use `cloneNode` method => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```js
const myTab = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')

console.log( 'lines .....= ', myTab.rows.length )
console.log( 'columns ...= ', myTab.rows[0].cells.length )
console.log( 'table[1,3] = ', myTab.rows[1].cells[3].textContent, '(value)')
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em }
td { border: 1px solid grey; width: 2em; height: 1em; }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>0.0</td><td>0.1</td><td>0.2</td><td>0.3</td><td>0.4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1.0</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td><td>1.4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2.0</td><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td><td>2.4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3.0</td><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td><td>3.4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```