# Checking for values in columns of html table with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to (when a JS function is called) check for certain values that are in specific columns in a cursory way.

Basically, let's say someone is trying to use a coupon but it only applies for shoes the color of brown or the size 9. I have test values in my JS, but I need to find a way to check both the size column for 9 and the color column for 'Brown'. If either one exists then I would trigger a success message.

I know I can get table row length and whatnot, but is there a way to parse HTML tables in this way with JS?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Size</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Leather</td>
            <td>Brown</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Canvas</td>
            <td>Grey</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Leather</td>
            <td>Black</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743557/how-to-show-first-two-rows-of-a-hidden-table-in-another-table/56744214#

Comment: Loop over the rows of the table. For each row, get the text of the appropriate cells, compare them with the search values, and do something if they match. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I guess I'm just not sure how to check the value of columns or loop the table with JavaScript. Would I do a loop and iterate the row but set the column names to their owm JS variable?

Comment: `if (row.cells[1].innerText == 'Brown' && row.cells[2].innerText == '9')`

Comment: Can I use header names instead or does it have to be index numbers?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your answer but I still can't find documentation on whether I can use column names? You say cells[1] but could I do something similar with cells['color']

Comment: No, there are no column names in the DOM. You could use classes, and `row.querySelector(".color")`

Comment: Ah, thanks @barmar I'll try that!